# php mail() to phpmailer

Tags: php, email

I have a php application which is currently using php mail() to send emails.
I want to use smtp (preferably sendgrid) to send mails as shared server has limit/hour.

### My code is as follows:

admin_sendmail.php

```
class sendmail
{
    public static function sendAccountActivateMail($to,$activate_code,$user_id,$user_name,$user_pwd)
    {
        $flg = false;
        try
        {
            $subject = 'Mysite Account Activation'; 

            $message  = "Welcome to Mysite! \n"; 
            $message .= "Please activate your account by clicking the link below \n";
            $message .= "http://myzone.mysite.com/account_activation.php?command=activate&surebuzz_code=$user_id&activation_code=$activate_code \n"; 
            $message .= "Username: $user_name \n"; 
            $message .= "Password: $user_pwd \n"; 

            $email  = "info@mysite.com";
            $headers = "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email";
            $flg = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $flg = false;
        }
        return $flg;
    }
```

}

Can anyone help convert this to use SMTP with phpmailer/swiftmailer or sendgrid?
I am pretty new to php. This was coded by someone else whom I have lost contact with.

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: SO won't rewrite this for you. Try to convert it yourself and come back when you've tried something.

Comment: You will find ready made solution for smtp with phpmailer. Just download it and try it first.

Comment: @Vinay http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial#2 you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use.

```
require_once ('class.phpmailer.php');
class myPHPMailer extends PHPMailer {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->IsSMTP();
        $this->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $this->SMTPSecure = "tls";  //Or SSL?
        $this->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $this->Port       = 587;    //Maybe 465 instead? SSL only?
        //$this->Port     = 25;
        $this->Username   = "xxx";
        $this->Password   = "xxx";
    }
        $mail             = new myPHPMailer();
        $mail->AddReplyTo("xxx@xxx.com","xxx");
        $mail->From       = "xxx@xxx.com.com";
        $mail->FromName   = "xxx";
        $mail->Subject    = "What ever";
        $mail->WordWrap   = 50; // set word wrap
        $mail->Body     = $msg;
        $mail->AddAddress("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx");
        $mail->Send();
```

Comment: Has class.phpmailer.php changed to phpmailer.inc.php?
There is another file called smtp.inc.php

I'll try to code and see if I can solve this. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @user1032531...I am getting this error

Fatal error: Class declarations may not be nested in /home/surebzz/public_html/app/admins123/admin_library/admin_sendmail.php on line 93

LINE 93 reads:
class myPHPMailer extends PHPMailer {

Comment: require("phpmailer.inc.php");$mail= new PHPMailer(); $mail->IsSMTP(); $mail->SMTPAuth= true; $mail->SMTPSecure= "tls"; $mail->Host= "smtp.gmail.com"; $mail->Port= 587; $mail->Username= "xxx@mydomain.com"; $mail->Password= "xxxxxx"; $mail->AddReplyTo("info@mydomain.com"); $mail->From= "info@mydomain.com"; $mail->FromName= "Website"; $mail->Subject= $subject; $mail->WordWrap= 50; $mail->Body = $message; $mail->AddAddress($to); $mail->Send(); } I am getting error: Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /home/surebzz/public_html/app/admins123/admin_library/phpmailer.inc.php on line 271

Comment: searched online..said to change $Encoding to:
$header[] = sprintf("Content-Transfer-Encoding: %s\n", $this->Encoding);

Did that...no errors now...but mail is NOT delivered...what could be problem?

Comment: Turned on debug and this is what is shown:

SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 550 SMTP AUTH is required for message submission on port 587 SMTP -> ERROR: DATA command not accepted from server: SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected